# Defining if statement for reading text file to constraint the reading values

Tags: python, if-statement

I am doing the following case, but I never did this before and now I am facing many problems, I need your help. Sorry if my question is amateurish.

I want to read two text files (3 columns and 1000 rows) and divide the values of column `I` inside both files by together `I1/I`. But If we have specific values of `n`, `t`, `n1`, `t1`.

```
n, t, I = np.genfromtxt('C:/...nu/I1.txt',unpack=True)
n1, t1, I1 = np.genfromtxt('C:...nu/I2.txt',unpack=True)
with open('C:/Users/esadr21/Desktop/uf/newInu/Inu101rat.txt', 'w') as d:
    if 1e2<n<3e5 and 1e1<t<3e1 and 1e-2<n1<1e-5 and 1e1<t1<2e6:
            rat = I1/I
            d.write("{0}\n".format(rat))
    else: pass
```

but this way doe not work.
Any help please?

Comment: Why are you using Numpy to *read* the files?  can you include a minimal example of the two files?  Please read [mcve]

Comment: @wwii Just I use it. I dont know. Easier maybe.

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: @wwii just 3 columns and 1000 rows. and numbers

Comment: Do you want to compare the same lines from each line -i.e. file1 line1 with file2 line1?

Comment: @wwii `I1/I` it means each value of columns `I1` should be divided by the value in column `I`. each row for the same roe, 1 for 1, 2 for 2. it should be easy, but my code do not anything

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely clear without the actual data, but it seems like `n`, `t`, `I` etc. are supposed to be the values on individual *lines* of the file, but you unpack the list of lines to those three variables. Instead, you should probably `zip` the data from the two files to get the individual variables for corresponding lines:

```
# read data consisting of multiple lines each; note: no unpack
data1 = np.genfromtxt('C:/...nu/I1.txt')
data2 = np.genfromtxt('C:...nu/I2.txt')

# zip and unpack lines to variables
for (n, t, I), (n1, t1, I1) in zip(data1, data2):
    if 1e2<n< 3e5 and 1e1<t<3e1 and 1e-2<n1<1e-5 and 1e1<t1<2e6:
        rat = I1 / I
        ...
```

Or keep using `unpack` and then `zip` and iterate the individual columns (Note that I'm using uppercase variables for the columns and lowercase for the individual values):

```
# read individual data columns
N, T, I = np.genfromtxt('C:/...nu/I1.txt', unpack=True)
N1, T1, I1 = np.genfromtxt('C:...nu/I2.txt', unpack=True)

# loop over zipped column to get individual variables
for n, t, i, n1, t1, i1 in zip(N, T, I, N1, T1, I1):
    if 1e2<n< 3e5 and 1e1<t<3e1 and 1e-2<n1<1e-5 and 1e1<t1<2e6:
        rat = i1 / i
        ...
```

(removed the output file to focus on the actual problem)

Comment: I will testu=ing this now. But n, t, I and n1, t1, I1 are columns with 1000 rows

Comment: @MaY Did not notice the `unpack` See my updated answer.

Comment: is there any way to say that: now if the number of rows after implementing this `if` for oneof  those text files is bigger than another one, just do the whole thing f we have value or something like this. for example after these `if` statement we have `500` rows in first text file and 190 in the second one

Comment: @MaY `zip` will loop only as long as there are entries in all iterables, i.e. for 500 and 190, it will only compare the first 190.